# Javascript table render very slow

Tags: javascript

This is my javascript

```
function makeTable() {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        fragment.appendChild(row);

        for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.toString() + ', ' + j.toString()));
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }

   var target = document.getElementById('target');
   target.appendChild(fragment);
};
```

This is my HTML

```
<input type="button" value="New Table" onClick="makeTable()"/>
<table id="target"></table>
```

When you click to render this table it takes over 10 seconds on a Chrome and Firefox browser. Anyway to speed this up ? When I render the table onload, its instant.

Comment: Realistically, this will run pretty slowly. You're adding 21,000 elements to the DOM. That's a bit excessive.

Comment: Visually, building it as html seems to be a bit [faster](http://jsfiddle.net/x2jgu7kx/)

Comment: Both Serge's fiddle and your original source run very fast (well under a second). Are you sure you weren't testing other things by mistake? Loading of resources for instance; many resources are cached and load much faster the second time you access them.

Comment: If you click on the button and start counting, it takes about 10 seconds before the table is actually rendered. To add to it, the browser freezes before its rendered. If you run makeTable() onload it is well below a second and no freezing at all.

Comment: The jsfiddle by Serge runs well below a second using Firefox but takes about 10 seconds on Chrome.

Comment: @user2636123 Runs in a fraction of a second on both browsers here; maybe a tad faster on Chromium.